# CodeIgniter Site unable to host

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I have developed a site which works perfectly on localhost. But when I'm hosting the `css`, `js`, `images` and `fonts` are not linking.

You can check it at http://think-exam.site88.net/

It should actually look like this when all is working fine.
[image: when hosted on localhost]

Here's My `config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

`url` hepler is also loaded.

The folder structure is like

```
- root
    -public html
     - application
     - system
     - assets
        - css
        - js
       index.php
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your base_url() I think this is base_url() problem. Can you please post your config file data.

Comment: Note: In old versions of codeIgniter you could leave you base_url config blank in config.php but now in codeIgniter 3 and up versions it would be best to set your base_url in config.php and don't leave it blank. Also make sure in new versions of codeIgniter you have only the first letter of filename and class name upper case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project you are using:

```
http://31.170.162.63/
```

in your site, and i try to access this image:

```
http://31.170.162.63/assets/images/logo-2.gif
```

This URL is returning the 404 not found page.

When i test this URL with same image:

```
http://think-exam.site88.net/assets/images/logo-2.gif
```

This URL is working fine, as you need.

**What actually you need:**

You need to set the `base_url()` in your `config.php` file as:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://think-exam.site88.net/';
```

And than you can use in your application as:

```
<?=base_url()?>assets/images/logo-2.gif
```